Easily removable wall that can insulate relatively well from fumes?
I'm trying to split a room into two, and I want to create a barrier to prevent fumes from traveling from one side to the other. I want to avoid putting up a traditional wall. Does anyone have any ideas for a quick and removable option, that can meet my requirements but still be easily reversible if the need arises?
Accordion walls with good sealing might work, but I couldn't find any good options online.

What are the fumes from?  Where are the fumes in the room coming from.  Would an exhaust fan work?

An exhaust fan wouldn't work in this scenario, the fumes are from projects being done in the bay. The intent is to split it so we can share the space.

Most fumes are usually not good for human health.  Ventilation will be needed for a sealed room.  A wall probably will be the best to seal, but can cheap out a bit and use decent 2x3s, thinner drywall and poly vapour barrier.  Tape the vapour barrier to the floor and ceiling.Really vapour barrier/heavy duty drop sheets tape to the floor and ceiling will work to keep the fumes in, plus letting the other person know if you pass out.

IMHO, odds are very low that you're going to find a ready made solution for this. Since you're working on "projects", just consider building something one of them. Also, as you're cordoning off a section of the room, make sure it's a section with a window so you can open the window and put in a couple of fans blowing out. Give your barrier some sort of one-way air inlet so you're drawing a very slight vacuum in your work area to help keep fumes from escaping to the outside. Odds are good that your seal at the ceiling/floor/walls will be just leaky enough to allow air flow in.

Folks doing construction/painting usually use plastic sheeting to control dust and reduce fumes these days, with poles holding it against the ceiling. Should be cheap and easily available from construction suppliers.
Of course if the fumes are from a point source, the better solution is an enclosure just around that source with its own exhaust fan. Commercially made "paint booths" are available up to fairly decent sizes, including in versions which can be set up quickly and then folded for storage.

I built many temporary barriers when doing remodel jobs. While you can use purpose-built hardware (extension poles, zipper sheets), a simple friction-fit framed wall is often the simplest approach.
Materials

A sheet of polyethylene, plastic tarp, or other impermeable material that's at least 2 feet (60cm) larger than the opening in both directions.
Lightweight lumber adequate to place top and bottom plates and supports every 2-3 feet (60-100cm).
A stapler or tacks
A strip of foam. felt, or other soft material to protect the ceiling and walls (optional)
Screws to secure the supports (optional)

Procedure

Cut top and bottom plates a bit short of the opening width. You want a slight gap to prevent surface damage.

Staple the top edge of the sheet to the upper face of the top plate. Consider rolling the plate into the sheet once or twice if size allows. Optionally add a foam or felt gasket strip over the plastic.

Cut supports the height of the opening minus the combined heights of the plates.

With one or more helpers, position the top plate against the ceiling and the bottom plate below it. Tuck the bottom of the sheet under the bottom plate, pulling it just taut.

Press supports between them, angling in from one side (parallel to the plates). They should fit snugly. Bump them toward vertical until they're adequately snug. (They don't need to be completely vertical when installed.) As you work, continue to make the sheet taut along the plate's length.

Optionally add a screw at the top and bottom into the respective plate to secure them.

Seal any gaps with additional rolled sheet or gasket material.


